# I have an array of numbers. I need to return a new array in which the duplicate numbers are in their own nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to take this array [1,2,4,591,392,391,2,5,10,2,1,1,1,20,20] and return a new array which sorts all the duplicate numbers into their own nested array.

it should return [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2], 4,5,10,[20,20], 391, 392,591].

I have messed around with for loops as well as the .map() method and can't seem to land on the solution. At this point I am almost just taking shots in the dark hoping something will work out. I am very new at javascript.

```
const cleaner = array1.map((num, index, array) => {
    if (array1.indexOf(num) >= index) {
        return num;
    } else {
        return array;
    }
    });
```

Comment: If someone asked you to do it with pen and paper, how would you do it? As a small hint in and of itself, the shown resulting array is sorted not only into arrays, but also sorted numerically — it's a good indicator that that's the first thing you could do, and then go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to collect the unique values then use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to create the subarrays for each value.

```js
const array = [1,2,4,591,392,391,2,5,10,2,1,1,1,20,20];

// defines a function that...
const arrange = array =>
  // creates array of unique values
  Array.from(new Set(array))
  // sorts unique values in ascending order
  .sort((a, b) => a - b)
  // creates a subarray for each unique value
  .map(key => array.filter(value => key === value))
  // unwraps unit length subarrays
  .map(subarray => subarray.length === 1 ? subarray[0] : subarray);

const cleaner = arrange(array);

console.log(JSON.stringify(cleaner));
```

This is not the most efficient approach, but it is considerably more readable (in my opinion) than procedural approaches using the `reduce()` method, and for an array of this length, the difference in execution time will be negligible.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `reduce`, see the comments in the snippet :

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {

  // check if the element exists in the accumulator
  const ndx = acc.findIndex(e => (Array.isArray(e) ? e.includes(curr) : e === curr));

  if (ndx === -1) {
    // if it doesn't exist, push it
    acc.push(curr);
  } else {
    // if it exists, check if it's an array
    if (Array.isArray(acc[ndx])) acc[ndx].push(curr); // if it is, push the current element
    else acc[ndx] = [acc[ndx], curr]; // convert the current element in accumulator to an array with the previous and the new elements
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to do that, you need to perform a few operations:

1. Count occurrence of each number.
2. Sort non-repeating numbers.
3. Map it to have either number (non-repeating), or array of repeated numbers.

```
const array = [1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20];
```

### Step 1

Let’s count items. For that, I would create an object that will keep a track of each.

```
const counted = array.reduce(
    (acc, current) => Object.assign(acc, { [current]: acc[current] ? acc[current] += 1 : 1 }),
    {}
);
```

Using reduce we create an object, which will look like that:

```
{
    '1': 5,
    '2': 3,
    '4': 1,
    '5': 1,
    // etc.
}
```

### Step 2

Let's sort elements:

```
const sorted = Object.keys(counted)
    .map(Number) // <-- we have to remember that object keys are strings
    .sort((a, b) => a - b);
```

### Step 3

Now that we have prepared object with counts and have them sorted, let’s put it together. If number in `counted` is 1 then we’ll insert value directly, otherwise we’ll transform it into array of values.

```
const final = sorted.map(
    (number) => counted[number] == 1
        ? number
        : Array.from({ length: counted[number] }, () => number)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object and use the implicit sorting.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20],
    result = Object.values(array.reduce((r, v) => {
        if (v in r) r[v] = [].concat(r[v], v);
        else r[v] = v;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```